# API REST & MySQL : using both auto increment ID and uuid

Tags: mysql, database, api, primary-key, uuid

I am creating a REST API with a MySQL database. I would like to know if using auto-incrementing IDs as primary keys, (to keep good performance) and unique uuid fields (used as API ID) is a bad idea? If so why?

(from Comment)  The purpose of the UUID is to provide an opaque id in the API, while using a simpler, more efficient, BIGINT for internal purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUIDs have these benefits:

- They can be created independently by multiple clients, while being unique.
- They obfuscate the ids.  (Example:  avoid hackers discovering valid ids.)

IDs have these benefits:

- Smaller disk space (and cache) needed, hence somewhat faster.
- Temporarily oriented ("recent" inserts are clustered "together").  This is a performance benefit for very large tables (or small RAMs).

"Natural" Primary keys (a column or combination of columns that is intrinsically unique):

- may be smaller
- may be faster
- more logical.
- Example: In the case of a many-to-many mapping table (just 2 ids pointing to two other tables), `PRIMARY KEY(a_id, b_id), INDEX(b_id, a_id)` is clearly faster and smaller.

UUIDs are 36 or 16 bytes; ids are 8 bytes or 4 or smaller.  A natural key *may* take 0 extra bytes (or may not).

To answer your question:  "It depends".

The tables I build have PKs:

1. Natural - 2/3 of the tables
2. Auto_inc - 1/3
3. UUID - essentially none.

(PS:  I find REST to be clumsy and provide no real benefits, so I avoid it.)

**Based on Comment**

Probably you what:

- An auto_inc id everywhere in the database;
- A UUID for opaquely sending to the user.  This avoids various hacking games that might be played with an auto_inc.

So, in the the main table,

```
CREATE TABLE main (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uuid BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE(uuid),
    ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

When creating a new row, compute a new UUID, strip the dashes and convert `FROM_HEX()`.

When sending a message to the user, include `uuid`, not `id`.

When receiving a reply message, quickly switch to using `id` by looking it up via that available index.  Perhaps this way:

```
SELECT id FROM main WHERE uuid = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I would like to know is if the combination of auto-inc id and uuid is good or not?

Comment: @Stov - "Combination"?  Why both?  [There is an obscure reason why you might want both.]  Almost always, one or the other suffices.  They each provide all the requirements for a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: If I use auto-inc ids as PK, I won't have performance issues (that I would have using uuids because of the unordered values and their size) and using another column (number) of type uuid will allow me to use it as an identifier for my API without having to expose the PK. At least that's what I think.

Comment: @Stov - Yes.  You could either have a 2 -column table like that.  Or add the UUID to the existing table and have an index on it.  (That `INDEX` would effectively be the same 2-column BTree.)

Comment: and I aadded sample code for such.